# Transform a [string,string] to Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

Hello everybody I have this string:

```
[JOLLY BLU at STAY SHIP,  Voy: 0275/11]
```

How I can turn this string in a String[]

```
value[0] = "JOLLY BLU at STAY SHIP";
value[1] = "Voy: 0275/11";
```

Thankyou much

Comment: why is this tagged as "android"?

Comment: @savinos Because Android uses Java as a programming language.

Comment: yes, I mean this is not specific to android in any way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
str = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1); // cut [ and ] off
String[] parts = str.split(",");
```

Comment: there's a typo, separator is "," and not ";"

Answer (score 4):

```
String s = "[JOLLY BLU at STAY SHIP,  Voy: 0275/11]";
String temp = s.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
// or String temp = s.substring(1, s.length() - 1);
String[] sArray = temp.split(",");
sArray[1] = sArray[1].trim(); // remove the whitespaces around the string
```

Comment: third line should probably be temp.split